# Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode4.3

When i try to make an archive for my App, i to it successfully, but with a weird warning:

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/Malek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fontenay-sous-Bois-elmujlurzvtkqdctznqivfpchsfq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Fontenay-sous-Bois/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Fontenay-sous-Bois.app/Fontenay-sous-Bois
AssertMacros: message,  file: /SourceCache/codesign_wrapper_Sim/Security-1245/codesign_wrapper/codesign_wrapper.c, line: 495
AssertMacros: profile,  file: /SourceCache/codesign_wrapper_Sim/Security-1245/codesign_wrapper/codesign_wrapper.c, line: 904
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: Failed to load provision profile from: /Users/Malek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fontenay-sous-Bois-elmujlurzvtkqdctznqivfpchsfq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Fontenay-sous-Bois/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Fontenay-sous-Bois.app/embedded.mobileprovisi
 - (null)
```

When i use to work with Xcode 4.2, everything went great, but since i upgraded to Xcode 4.3, i keep seeing this Warning, please help :)

Comment: Have you checked - Product -> Edit Scheme ->  Archive Profile -> Build configuration (check if this is set correctly to distribution)

Comment: Hi, thanx for your tip :) Actually, i check it, it was for Distribution, but still getting the same Warning, i clean it, although, always i get the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you might need to delete from sim/device, Clean from Xcode, and rebuild.  Have you tried this?

If so, go to the Organizer, tap the Projects button, find your project and tap the button to delete Derived Data.

From there, make sure you have the correct Distribution Profile selected in both the App Build Settings AND the Target Build Settings.  Sometimes these get out of sync for some reason.

Comment: I had this issue, in my case it was the Target Build Settings that was not set to Distribution... Thanks

Comment: Mine was also out of sync with each other!

Answer (score 3):

Check that the TARGET (and not only the Project) is setup with the correct Code Signing Identity for Release

Comment: This solved my specific problem. It turns out XCode automatically selected the Wildcard Adhoc profile.

Answer (score 3):

please also make sure that you don't have your code in unauthorized directory. e.g.(in usb.etc)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select "iOS Device" and not "Simulator" in the upper left corner